# Multiplication in Django view

Tags: django

I am trying to represent decimal values as percentages in a template. Specifically, I have several fields in a model with values such as '0.4000000059604645'. In models.py I have it representated as

```
information_percent = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

And in a view I have:

```
    org = Organizationaldata.objects.get(name=organization) 
    information_percent = org.information_percent
```

What I cannot figure out is how to get this to show as, for instance, '40.0' in the template. I have done a lot of searching and I can't figure out how to multiply the value by 100, or some other technique that will deliver the intended result.

And suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [built-in floatformat template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat).

For example:

**views.py**

```
org = Organizationaldata.objects.get(name=organization)
information_percent = 100 * org.information_percent
```

**template.html**

```
<span>Info percent: {{ information_percent|floatformat:1 }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, RJ! This worked great for me. In trying out your code I discovered what I think was an additional problem: in my SQLite database the field type was not indicated. I went into SQLite Manager, changed it to 'FLOAT' and then your code worked! (btw, I just started using South with this db, and I may have been assuming that the migration was changing the field type in the db; but, since I had imported the csv data into the table then ran the migration, this may not have been the case). Anyways, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
information_percent = int(org.information_percent*100)
```

If you want the fractional part you can extend it to:

```
information_percent = int(org.information_percent*100) + (org.information_percent*100 - int(org.information_percent*100))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but will make '16.654' be '16'. For other views this might work well for me, so I appreciate the answer.

Comment: No problem. As you said, it only works if you have numbers in range [0, 1] and want to transform them into a percentage...